# Which web server should I use in win2003 as production environment?

Tags: windows, webserver

It should at least support asp/asp.net,best support PHP too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running ASP.NET, then IIS is the defacto web server on Windows 2003 server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998483%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx

To install IIS on Windows Server 2003

1.

```
  Click Start, point to Control Panel, and then click Add or Remove Programs.
```

2.

```
  In Add or Remove Programs, click Add/Remove Windows Components.
```

3.

```
  In the Windows Components Wizard, under Components, select Application Server.
```

4.

```
  Click Next.
```

5.

```
  After the wizard completes the installation, click Finish.
```

Comment: I have not tried running PHP on Win 2003. But there seems to be way to run PHP on IIS 6/Win2003 server. Take a look at http://www.visualwin.com/PHP/

Answer (score 0):

If ASP or ASP.NET support is important, and you're running on Windows 2003 Server, I don't see any reason *not* to use IIS.

Comment: How to install IIS?Does it need to compile?